# Postgres - Sum Of The Difference Between Two TIMESTAMPS For All Users

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-difference

I have two tables, `users` and `trips`.

```
users:{
  id: BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  name:  VARCHAR(255)
  phone:  VARCHAR(255)
}

trips:{
 id: BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
 user_id: BIGINT   
 started_at: TIMESTAMP
 finished_at: TIMESTAMP
}
```

I have to write a query that returns id, name, phone and the correct component of the number of hours of users' trips (sum of the difference between the start and finish times of their trips), in descending order according to the number of hours (if the number of hours of two users is the same, the user with the smaller ID must come earlier).

so far I've come up with following query but it does not give correct answers

```sql
SELECT id, name, phone, FLOOR(trips_length)
  FROM users JOIN (
      SELECT user_id, SUM(
          DATE_PART('hour', finished_at - started_at)  + 
          DATE_PART('minute', finished_at - started_at) / 60  +
          DATE_PART('second', finished_at - started_at) / 3600) AS trips_length
      FROM trips GROUP BY user_id ) AS twl ON id = user_id
  ORDER BY trips_length DESC, users.id ASC;
```

Comment: Include some sample data and expected output in your question.

Comment: You're probably running into integer division. But doesn't Postgres let you do `sum(finished_at - started_at)`?

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting one timestamp from another gives you an `interval`. That interval can be summed directly:

```
SELECT id, name, phone, trips_length
FROM users 
JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, SUM(finished_at - started_at) as trips_length
  FROM trips 
  GROUP BY user_id 
) AS twl ON id = user_id
ORDER BY trips_length DESC, users.id ASC;
```